# Can dictionaries be used in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have been looking up dictionaries in C# and they seem to be highly useful, and was wondering if it is possible to use them in C++ as I have tried to search for dictionaries in C++ but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent that I can find. Is there some sort of library that I could download and include to the project or is there a function which does the same thing just with a different name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a corresponding type in STL, that's called `std::map`.

It has the same basic functionality as a .NET Dictionary, but the implementation is quite different. `std::map` is internally based on a red-black tree datastructure, while `Dictionary` uses a hash table internally.

If you're just looking for something with the same behaviour, `std::map` will do, but if you have large amounts of data you have to be aware of the different performance characteristics.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` implements dictionary functionality using a hash table (like C#'s `Dictionary`)--__IF__ you have C++11

Comment: @SchighSchagh: well, there is always `boost::unordered_map` otherwise ;)

Comment: Thanks for comments about C++11 - been too long since I did actual C++ coding, so didn't know `std::unordered_map` exists.

Answer (score 8):

There's `std::map` for logarithmic access time (usually based on a tree implementation) and `std::unordered_map` (since C++11) for expected constant, worst-case linear access time (usually based on a hashing implementation).

Comment: I'd say that the standard requires a hashing implementation for `std::unordered_map`, and even a very specific version of collision management.  Otherwise, what do functions like `bucket_count()` and `load_factor()` mean?

Comment: @JamesKanze It would indeed be quite difficult to come up with a different implementation of `std::unordered_map`. I was just trying to stress the fact that the standard does not actually require a particular implementation, only the "observable effects" (in common sense, not in the standard definition).

Comment: *usually based on a hashing implementation*: I would say that since the only predicates that are provided are a hasher (default to `std::hash<Key>`) and a comparator (default to `std::equal_to<Key>`), and considering the complexity constraints, it **must** be some kind of hash-table. Furthermore, the requirements of memory stability also constrain the design-space (open-addressing with relocation on rehashing is precluded, for example).

Answer (score 6):

[std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is like a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use map in C++ 
The basic format of using a map is -

```
    std::map<Key_type, Value_Type> ;
```

Example -

```
    std::map<std::string,std::string> x = {{"A","ABC"},{"B","DEF"}}
```