# expected primary-expression received in g++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, g++

This code compiles successfully with VS, but when porting it to Linux and compiling with g++ it errors out.

```
template <class Key, class  Value> 
void Dictionary<Key, Value>::set(const Key &key, Value value)
{
    typename Dictionary<Key,Value>::iterator i = this->find(key);
    if (i == this->end())   
    {
        access(&key, &value, eINSERT);
        this->insert(value_type(key, value));       
    }
    else
    {
        access(&key, &i->second, eCLEAR);
        dispose(i->second);
        access(&key, &value, eSET);
        i->second = value;
    }
}

template <class Key, class  Value> class PtrDictionary : public Dictionary<Key, Value>;

class Processor
{
    private:
        ptrdictionary<const string,const type*>         m_Types;

    void Processor::add(const string name, const Type* t)
    {
        if (m_Types.get(name))
            error("Type '"+string(name)+"' already defined", eParseError);

        m_Types.set(name, t); // this is where the error is received
    }
}
```

The error is:

> ../Packages/Dictionary.h: In instantiation of 'void Dictionary::set(const Key&, Value) [with Key = const
>   std::basic_string; Value = const AsmLoader::Type*]':
>   Instructions.cpp:94:21:   required from here
>   ../Packages/Dictionary.h:79:37: error: expected primary-expression
>   this->insert(value_type(key, value));

Update:

value_type is an object in std::map, and all it took for g++ to compile the code was to add this:

```
typedef typename map<const Key, Value>::value_type value_type;
```

Thanks everyone for your comments, this is my first time using SO and this is a very complex code so I forgot to specify this part...

Comment: Have you tried `this->m_Types.set(name, t)`

Comment: I have, the error remains the same...

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: The error says that `this->insert(value_type(key, value));` in the `set()` function is causing the problem.  What is `value_type()`?

Comment: @ 0x499602D2 This is the full error. 
@ NathanOliver value_type() is a type from std::map.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.  Without that, we have to invent what the rest of your code says in our mind.  This is not a request that you dump your entire code base here, but rather a request for a MCVE.

Comment: thanks for your help, the issue was indeed with the value_type - see update.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does not look as if this can be implemented in the same fashion as in VS. In researching this, I found:

[Can dictionaries be used in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417463/can-dictionaries-be-used-in-c)

They suggested using std::map in STL as a similar method in C++ (without .NET). In case the above link changes, here is a quote from the answer supplied:

> There is a corresponding type in STL, that's called std::map.
>
> It has the same basic functionality as a .NET Dictionary, but the
>   implementation is quite different. std::map is internally based on a
>   red-black tree datastructure, while Dictionary uses a hash table
>   internally.
>
> If you're just looking for something with the same behaviour, std::map
>   will do, but if you have large amounts of data you have to be aware of
>   the different performance characteristics.

** Caveat - I am still learning, so apologies if this is off the mark of your original question. Hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @cpburnz I will remember that and update the answer --- much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
value_type is an object in std::map, and all it took for g++ to compile the code was to add this:

```
typedef typename map<const Key, Value>::value_type value_type;
```